# Is there any way to apply filter in Action Bar in Android

Tags: java, android, performance, android-studio, android-fragments

I am working on a project in which `MainActivity` is the only Activity that has several Fragments with ViewPage and each `Fragment` has displaying data using a `RecyclerView` custom Adapter which implements a `Filterable` interface. The `MainActivity`  is

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private TabLayout mTabLayout;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mToolbar=findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        mTabLayout=findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        mViewPager=findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        PagerAdpater adpater=new PagerAdpater(getSupportFragmentManager());

        adpater.addFragment(new GreetingFragment(),"Greeting");
        adpater.addFragment(new NumberFragment(),"Numbers");
        adpater.addFragment(new EatingOutFragment(),"Eating Out");
        adpater.addFragment(new ColorFragment(),"Colors");
        adpater.addFragment(new ClothesFragment(),"Clothes");
        adpater.addFragment(new FamilyFragment(),"Family");

        mViewPager.setAdapter(adpater);
        mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);




    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbar_search_menu,menu);
        MenuItem menuItem=menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

        SearchView searchView=(SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setQueryHint("Type here to search");
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                return true;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
}
```

As you can see in code. The SeachView in toolBar is already been set up. And it is showing in the action bar. But I want to search the content of fragments with a getting their content from a DataService Class.  I want when I click on the search icon a list of content will appear and I can filter them.

**If you don't get my point just me know, I will edit  my Question **

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to say, you want a page with the result of your search to show up when you click on the search button/icon? if thats not what you're saying then kindly edit your question.